# got error "can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str" in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have got error can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str on my logger.exception("failed to create"+ e) line.

code is here :

```
 except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        logger.exception("failed to create"+ e)
        connection.rollback()
        return {
            "statusCode": 5000,
            'headers': {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
            "body": json.dumps({
                "error": True,
                "message": "failed"
            }),
        }
```

Comment: `+ str(e)`.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your exception to str. Please see the below code.

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    logger.exception("failed to create"+ str(e))
    connection.rollback()
    return {
        "statusCode": 5000,
        'headers': {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
        "body": json.dumps({
            "error": True,
            "message": "failed"
        }),
    }
```

Comment: better yet 3.6+ use fstring `logger.exception(f"failed to create: e")`

Answer (score 0):

The good practice is to pass an exception to the logger:

```py
logger.exception("failed to create %s", e)
```

such that error message template always be the same and allows to use more sophisticated logic or services to aggregate errors, filters them and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `logger.exception("failed to create %s", e)`